# Wordpress 4.8 - Can't find variable: wp

Tags: core

After the update to **Wordpress 4.8** my widget's textarea has disappeared and my console says:

```
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: wp
Global Code (widgets.php:202)
```

Looking at the file I can identify this line causing the issue:

```
wp.textWidgets.init();
```

Now, I've got installed many plugins but even deactivating all those I can't solve it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to enqueue the editor scripts manually, after 4.8, using `wp_enqueue_editor()` in your theme/plugin: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/05/20/editor-api-changes-in-4-8/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this didn't resolved the issue. My theme actually had a function to defer javascript which was the main cause!

Answer (score -1):

I actually had to restore manually the Wordpress core and to deactivate a function in my theme which deferred all the javascript.